# How to use same footer in all pages in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm developing a music app.

In my project, I have 2 pages 1. **`albumname`** page and 2. **`modal`** page (modal popup)

I have listed a lot of songs in **`albumname.html`** page. When the user clicks on a particular song, then artist name, artist title, pause/play button, next/previous button along with the song duration (progress bar) will display in the footer (`albumname.html` page).

If user click that footer,Then i need to show Songs name,image and song duration in **`modal`** page

Here I attached the Images for your reference..By seeing the image you will understand that what i need

[image - albunname page with footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHfxW.png)
[image - modal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SavPB.png)

Comment: What have you tried? What issues are you facing?

Comment: I have showed songs with time duration in footer,I need to show same time duration in other page @suvartheec

Comment: I have a page `albumname.html` and `albumname.ts`..I need to use  albumname components `albumname.ts` in `modal.ts` page

Comment: Did you know answer for this? @Utpaul

Answer (score 0):

You can try put your footer code in app.html file. 
For example you will try this:

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage">
</ion-nav>
<ion-footer>
 <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-title>Footer text</ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Hi..in my project,when user click particular song i show artist name,song duration(progress bar)  and nxt/prev button in footer..after,when user click footer,then modal popup will shown to user.here i hav issue, In that modal popup page, i got artist name, song image..but i cant get song duration as same as in footer @Paul Wilker Landaeta Flores

Comment: please, could you share me the screens for understanding you?

Comment: I edited my question..now i think you will clearly understand..plz see the image..I want like that @Paul Wilker Landaeta Flores